# Elasticsearch filtering aggregated results where count greater than x

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got the following elastic search query in order to get the highest total ms from Elastic Search grouped by market id.

```
    {
  "from": 0,
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
  "filtered": {
    "filter": {
      "and": [
        {
          "term": {
            "@type": "tradelog"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": "now-7d",
              "lt": "now"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "TotalMs": {
              "gte": 200,
              "lt": 2000
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }

},
"aggregations": {
      "the_name": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "Market",
            "order" : { "totalms_avg" : "desc" }
         },
         "aggregations": {
            "totalms_avg": {
               "avg": {
                  "field": "TotalMs"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This query returns several buckets that only have 1 result which are outliers in my data so I do not want them to be included.  Is it possible to filter out any buckets with a count of less than 5?  The elastic search equivalent to SQLs 'HAVING' clause.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [`min_doc_count` setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_minimum_document_count_3)

```
...
"aggregations": {
      "the_name": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "Market",
            "order" : { "totalms_avg" : "desc" },
            "min_doc_count": 5
         },
         "aggregations": {
            "totalms_avg": {
               "avg": {
                  "field": "TotalMs"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```